# How to run a PHP script with cronjob?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, cron-task

I'm trying to run a PHP script, like writing something in a txt file. If I manually load the file it works, but not with a cron job. I have cPanel and I followed what I read in the help page, but nothing works.

I tried this command

```
php -q /user/public_html/folder/cronTest.php
```

but it didn't work. I also tried

```
/user/local/bin/php -q /cronTest.php
```

[as it says here](http://support.modwest.com/content/5/125/en/can-i-run-a-php-script-on-cron.html).

I also tried to put `#!/user/public_html/bin/php -q` at the top of the file, but that didn't work either. I've also tried to change file permissions with similar results.

I really need to learn how to use cronjobs, cause I'll have a lot of work where it is needed.

I intend to use cPanel to set corncobs, so I hope the problem is with the command and/or the in code in the PHP file.

Comment: Did you actually use `/user/` instead of `/usr/`.  The latter is the normal way of spelling that path.

Comment: user needs to be the user name - i think!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
php -q /home/your_username/public_html/folder/cronTest.php
```

Also, if you can't find a solution, I'd suggest you to contact your hosting provider as they might be able to help you faster, or even fix a misconfiguration that might be causing the problem.

**EDIT**: Got it to work by using:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/your_username/public_html/path/to/script.php
```

Comment: Thank you Tom for the advice, but i allready contact them, but they help in things related with the server, etc...they say i need to fnd help near programares, cause the help team is not for this kind of problems. And because is my first time with cronjobs...i googled a lot for this subject, but i could't solve it. Thanx.

Comment: Is there any `error_log` file in the same directory as the script you're trying to run? It might have some useful information. Also, give `/usr/local/bin/php -q /cronTest.php` a go, as suggested by Conspicuous Compiler. `/usr/local/bin/php` it's the path were the  binary is usually at.

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment I meant `/usr/local/bin/php -q`, as the path to the PHP file may differ because of server configuration. Try it together with the several file path's you already tried.

Comment: I realy have a problem here! `/usr/local/bin/php -q /home2/user_name/public_html/consulta24/cronTest.php` Now i'm using this, should i replace "local" for "home2/user_name/peblic_html"? I also tryied just `/usr/local/bin/php -q /consulta24/cronTest.php`, but nothing!

Comment: Just try to replace `/home2/` with `/home/` and `user_name` with your actual username (the username you use on cPanel's login), like so: `/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/your_actual_username_here/public_html/consulta24/cronTest.php`. Just for reference, the `/usr/local/bin/php` path is an absolute path beginning in the root directory (`/`) and points to the php executable. So nothing needs to be changed in this path, the only thing you need to change in the example I give above is your username.

Comment: Thanx @TomS, but is not working. I was already using my username, and now i replaced `/home2/` with `/home/` as you said, but...not working. I realy don't know what can be the problem.

Comment: I have great news!! It's working and the way you said! Well almost cause i had to change `/usr/local/bin...` to `usr/bin...` and when i saw it was working. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Happy to hear that :) I edited my answer to document the working version of the command, as it might be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

We use cron to run nightly tasks in a php facebook game.  We do it by using curl like this:

```
/usr/bin/curl http://www.ourdomain.com/page.php
```

If I remember right we had some issues using localhost to try to avoid external lookups.  Also we tried using php command line execution, which mostly worked but caused a few strange bugs.